Making sense of 私の半分キャラデザ原画のゲーム

私の半分キャラデザ原画のゲームが発表になりました。

I can tell that this sentence means "A game, where the half of the character designs are done by me, got released." However, I am not sure about the grammar involved. It seems like the clause 私の半分キャラデザ原画 modifies ゲーム. I wonder if の in 私の半分キャラデザ原画 functions like が. 私の半分キャラデザ原画 literally means "I got credited to the half of the character designs"?

This sentence likely means "半分キャラデザ・半分原画のゲーム". We usually use "半分A半分B" to say "half-A, half-B", but the second 半分 seems to be omitted.
Generally, キャラデザ involves creating reference images (typically 三面図) that serve as the basis for all 原画, while 原画 involves creating many images based on the reference design. This person is probably saying that they played both roles partially (i.e., they did キャラデザ but created some 原画 as well). The interpretation that they worked on "half of the characters" seems unlikely from both a grammatical and industry practice standpoint.
